# Generar un ciclo del 1 al 100 en grupos de 5 y con tabulación entre cada numero

Tags: php, array

Estoy intentando crear un ciclo que muestre  100 números agrupados entre 5 con una tabulación entre ellos tal que así:

[image: ejemplo]

Tengo hecho este código pero no consigo que me funcione:

```
    <?php

$max_num = 101;
$contador =0;
for ($x=1;$x<$max_num;$x++) 
{
    $contador++;
 
    if (fmod($contador, 5) == 1)
    {  
    echo "<br>";    
    }
   echo $x. "    ";
}

?>
```

Gracias.

Edit. Con esto en el if me funcionan los números: (fmod($contador, 5) == 1).
Actualizado, me falta que me detecte la tabulación, \t no lo detecta.

He conseguido que lo haga pero no se si es la opción mas recomendada:

```
echo $x."&nbsp"."&nbsp"."&nbsp"."&nbsp"."&nbsp";
```

Comment: `\t` es un tabulador en `php`, pero `html` lo interpreta como un espacio simple. En su lugar debes usar `echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';` que significa _non-breaking space_ en 4 veces o la cantidad de espacios que consideres usar para tu tabulación.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <?php

$max_num = 101;
$contador =0;
echo "<pre>";
for ($x=1;$x<$max_num;$x++) 
{
    if ($contador%5 ==0)
    {  
    echo "<br>";    
    }       
   echo $x."\t";
   $contador++;
}
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Yo lo dejaria asi

Comment: No funciona exactamente como en la imagen y no me aparece una tabulación, parece ser que el \t no lo detecta? PD. aqui poniendo $contador%5 ==1 si funciona

Comment: he realizado algunos cambios y esta probado